# Why is the intersections between $f(x)=x^{2}+x^{-2}-3$ and the x-axis resembles $\varphi$?

Tags: functions, reference-request, golden-ratio

The story behind this is quite silly, I was messing around with functions in geogebra, inputting several functions to see their properties, until I was amazed by something i don't know about.

[image: screenshot]

Apparently, the intersections (unfortunately I don't know how the're named in english) between $f(x)=x^{2}+x^{-2}-3$ and the x-axis resembles $\varphi$, in the screenshot i've attached you can see it reveals the first 8 digits of $\varphi$ correctly. Can someone explain to me why this happens? I don't believe it's just a coincidence and I'm definitely missing something.

Comment: $x^2+x^{-2}-3 = x^{-2}(x^4-3x^2+1)=x^{-2}(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1)$

Comment: It is actually the golden ratio along with its inverse and their negatives, not just an approximation thereof. @MatthewTowers gives the reason for why that is.

Comment: The reason only the first $8$ digits are correct is that computers are bad at exactly solving equations.

Answer (score 3):

The intersection points are the solutions to the equation
$$x^2+x^{-2}-3=0.$$
The solutions are precisely the (nonzero) solutions to the equation
$$x^2(x^2+x^{-2}-3)=0,$$
or equivalently
$$x^4-3x^2+1=0.$$
It turns out that this polynomial factors as the product of two quadratic polynomials:
$$x^4-3x^2+1=(x^2-x-1)(x^2+x-1).$$
And of course the golden ratio $\varphi$ and its conjugate $\varphi^{-1}=\varphi-1$ are precisely the roots of
$$x^2+x-1=0.$$
And similarly their negatives $-\varphi$ and $-\varphi^{-1}$ are precisely the roots of
$$(-x)^2+(-x)-1=0,$$
or equivalently
$$x^2-x-1=0.$$
So the four solutions to the original equation are precisely $\pm\varphi$ and $\pm\varphi^{-1}$.